# Where to place resources in Grails project?

Tags: grails, resources, groovy

I am wondering if there is a designated place for resource files in a Grails application? I have a csv file that gets loaded into a map (nothing major) but didn't quite know where to put it in the project.

So my question is, is there a dedicated place in the project to place this file? (If so, where?) Or is it better to place it outside of the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the csv is going to need updating from time to time, I'd put it external to your grails folder, and point to it from config.groovy.

If it's basically a static file, I'd put it in src/java/resources, and load it with something like this.class.getResource("/resources/file.csv") as you would with a regular java app

Comment: Ah, alright it will have to be updated from time to time. Thank you for the reply Tim

Comment: Or use:  Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("resources/file.csv")  (added as edit, but it haven't been approved)