# Where to place, and how to access a jQuery plugin in a Grails application?

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy, grails-orm

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077614/where-to-place-resources-in-grails-project).  **I am wondering where I would place a jQuery plugin in my Grails application**, specifically the [jQuery numeric plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/).

Once I have that plugin in the proper location, how do I access it from my view?  I ask this because when I use jQuery in Grails (version 1.3.7) I use the plugin I found [here](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery), and to access jQuery after installation of that plugin I use the following code in my `<head>` tag:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
```

So with that said, **what code do I need in my head tag so I can access the numeric plugin?**

Comment: I had this same doubt! good you have asked this before! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Add your `.js` file(s) to `web-app/js/`, which will make them available in the deployed application under `<context-root>/js/`
2. Add this tag to your header, either in the main layout, or a GSP if not needed everywhere.

   `<g:javascript src="plugin.jquery.js"/>`

[See here for more information on the `g:javascript` tag.](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html)

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned, if you need to add resources, such as images or css, add them to `web-app/images/` or `web-app/css/`, respectively, and [include them using `<g:resource>`](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Also didn't realize that placing the reference in the `main.gsp` file placed it in all your views.

Comment: Why <g:javascript src="plugin.jquery.js"/> instead of <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>?

Comment: @Brad Rhoads - Please read the manual for specifics (linked above).  In short, library/plugin refers to something completely different, and is limited to the supported JS libraries.

Comment: @Brad Rhoads `<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>` is how you actually access the jQuery library in Grails (1.3.7) when using the [Grails jQuery plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery). `<g:javascript src="plugin.jquery.js"/>` is what you will use to access a plugin WRITTEN FOR jQuery, NOT an actual Grails plugin. Please note too that the `"plugin.jquery.js"` portion could be ANY JavaScript file, it does not have to be just a plugin written for jQuery. For example it could be a javascript file called `"myFunctions.js"` that you have personally written.