# Where to place resources in Grails 3 project?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077738/288341) answer addresses this problem for a Grails 2 project, but does not work for a Grails 3 project.  For instance, in a Grails 2 project I was able to put an xsl file in `/src/groovy/myapp/resources/` and load it similar to what the linked answer suggested...

```
this.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myapp/resources/my_xsl.xsl") // Returns an java.io.InputStream
```

...but that does not work for Grails 3 when the same file is placed in `src/main/groovy/myapp/resources/`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `src/main/resources`

Comment: Just to clarify it is sufficient to write `this.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my_xsl.xsl")` if `my_xsl.xsl` is located at `src/main/resource/my_xsl.xsl`